# XSLT 1.0 template How to retrieve the values from a second occurrence after logic to skip second occurrence altogether

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<DocumentElement>
<Sheet1>
<FIELD_1>HD</FIELD_1>
<FIELD_2>2024</FIELD_2>
<FIELD_3>90655</FIELD_3>
<FIELD_13>667</FIELD_13>
</Sheet1>
<Sheet1>
<FIELD_1>DT</FIELD_1>
<FIELD_2>496</FIELD_2>
<FIELD_13>0339618701316335</FIELD_13>
<FIELD_22>DMax</FIELD_22>
<FIELD_30>8.41</FIELD_30>
<FIELD_65>0.16</FIELD_65>
</Sheet1>
<Sheet1>
<FIELD_1>DT</FIELD_1>
<FIELD_2>496</FIELD_2>
<FIELD_13>0339618701316335</FIELD_13>
<FIELD_22>Sign</FIELD_22>
<FIELD_30>2.50</FIELD_30>
</Sheet1>
</DocumentElement>
```

The following stylesheet is creating the XML that follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt' xmlns:var='urn:var' xmlns:user='urn:user' exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl var user'  version='1.0'>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>  
  <xsl:template match="/DocumentElement">
    <DocumentElement>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(/DocumentElement/Sheet1[1]/FIELD_1) = 'HD' and normalize-space(/DocumentElement/Sheet1[2]/FIELD_1) = 'DT'">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Sheet1[normalize-space(FIELD_1) = 'HD' and normalize-space(FIELD_2) != 'CusId' and normalize-space(FIELD_2) != 'CusID']" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Sheet1[number(FIELD_2) = FIELD_2 and normalize-space(FIELD_1) != 'DT']" />
        </xsl:otherwise>

      </xsl:choose>
    </DocumentElement>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template priority="1"  match="Sheet1[normalize-space(FIELD_1) = 'HD']">
    <Invoice>
      <Ships>
        <xsl:variable name="prevC" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[normalize-space(FIELD_1) = 'DT' and FIELD_2 != 'CustomerId' and FIELD_2 != 'TrackingNbr'])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="newC" select="count(following-sibling::*[normalize-space(FIELD_1) = 'HD'][1]/preceding-sibling::*[normalize-space(FIELD_1) = 'DT' and FIELD_2 != 'CustomerId' and FIELD_2 != 'TrackingNbr'])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(following-sibling::*[ normalize-space(FIELD_1) = 'HD'][1])" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[normalize-space(FIELD_1) = 'DT'][position() &lt; ($newC - $prevC + 1) or $pos = 0]"   >
          <xsl:with-param name="data" select="FIELD_3" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </Ships>
    </Invoice>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template priority="1" match="Sheet1[normalize-space(FIELD_1) = 'DT']" >
    <xsl:param name="scac"/>
    
      <Ship>
        <Lines>
          <Line>
    <xsl:attribute name="ReferenceNumber" >
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(FIELD_13)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

            <LineCharge >
              <xsl:attribute name="Charge" >
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="normalize-space(FIELD_22) = 'Sign'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'TS5'"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'TS0'"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Amount" >
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(FIELD_30,'$,()',''),'###0.00')"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </LineCharge>
            
          </Line>
        </Lines>
      </Ship>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML OUTPUT:

```
<DocumentElement>
<Invoice>
<Ships>
<Ship>
<Lines>
<Line ReferenceNumber="0339618701316335">
<LineCharge Charge="TS0" Amount="8.41"/>
<LineCharge Charge="TS2" Amount="0.16"/>
</Line>
</Lines>
</Ship>
<Ship>
<Lines>
<Line ReferenceNumber="0339618701316335">
<LineCharge Charge="TS0" Amount="2.50"/>
</Line>
</Lines>
</Ship>
</Ships>
</Invoice>
</DocumentElement>
```

The first goal: Create one Ship element whenever there are multiple Sheet1 elements with identical values in FIELD_13. The following if statement was added above  in the code to prevent the second Ship element from being captured:

```
<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[normalize-space(FIELD_1) = 'DT' and FIELD_13 = current()/FIELD_13])">
```

NEW OUTPUT shows only one Ship element, which is correct:

```
<DocumentElement>
<Invoice>
<Ships>
<Ship>
<Lines>
<Line ReferenceNumber="0339618701316335">
<LineCharge Charge="TS0" Amount="8.41"/>
</Line>
</Lines>
</Ship>
</Ships>
</Invoice>
</DocumentElement>
```

The new issue is that the second LineCharge element is now skipped.

```
<LineCharge Charge="TS0" Amount="2.50"/>
```

I still need the 2nd LineCharge element that was nested in the second Ship element, but this time, as a sub element in the first Ship element, as seen below:

```
<DocumentElement>
<Invoice>
<Ships>
<Ship>
<Lines>
<Line ReferenceNumber="0339618701316335">
<LineCharge Charge="TS0" Amount="8.41"/>
<LineCharge Charge="TS5" Amount="2.50"/>
</Line>
</Lines>
</Ship>
</Ships>
</Invoice>
</DocumentElement>
```

How do I achieve this final XML?

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Comment: Please reduce the example code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve]. You have even code that you don't need at all, such as an `xsl:key` element that isn't used anywhere.

Comment: "Create one Ship element whenever there are multiple Sheet1 elements with identical values in sub element FIELD_13." I don't see that your stylesheet "currently achieves this". In the given example I would expect to see two Ship elements in the output. I am guessing the xsl:key element was meant to be used in Muenchian grouping but no actual grouping is being performed. The second goal I could not understand at all. What is the "second occurrence of Sheet1"? If there is to be grouping, should you count within the group?

Comment: I have added some clarification.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have revised the code to only show the part that can reproduce the output. Also provided a little more clarification. Thanks!

Comment: @y.arazim I have added some clarification, which hopefully paints a better picture.

Comment: I still don't get it. The only thing I can say at this point is that your testing for preceding siblings is not a good grouping strategy. You should employ the Muenchian method (as you seemingly started). There are many examples you can find here on SO but you should start by reading the original article: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of Muenchian grouping that may get you started:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="key1" match="Sheet1[FIELD_1='DT']" use="FIELD_13"/>

<xsl:template match="/DocumentElement">
    <DocumentElement>
        <Invoice>
            <Ships>
                <!-- group by FIELD_13 -->
                <xsl:for-each select="Sheet1[FIELD_1='DT'][generate-id()=generate-id(key('key1', FIELD_13)[1])]">
                    <Ship>
                        <Lines>
                            <Line ReferenceNumber="{FIELD_13}">
                                <!-- process current group -->
                                <xsl:for-each select="key('key1', FIELD_13)">
                                    <LineCharge Charge="" Amount="{FIELD_30}"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </Line>
                        </Lines>
                    </Ship>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Ships>
        </Invoice>
    </DocumentElement>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XML input of:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>HD</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_13>100</FIELD_13>
  </Sheet1>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>DT</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_13>101</FIELD_13>
    <FIELD_30>8.41</FIELD_30>
  </Sheet1>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>DT</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_13>101</FIELD_13>
    <FIELD_30>2.50</FIELD_30>
  </Sheet1>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>DT</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_13>102</FIELD_13>
    <FIELD_30>5.62</FIELD_30>
  </Sheet1>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>DT</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_13>103</FIELD_13>
    <FIELD_30>4.59</FIELD_30>
  </Sheet1>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>DT</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_13>103</FIELD_13>
    <FIELD_30>9.97</FIELD_30>
  </Sheet1>
</DocumentElement>
```

you will get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Invoice>
    <Ships>
      <Ship>
        <Lines>
          <Line ReferenceNumber="101">
            <LineCharge Charge="" Amount="8.41"/>
            <LineCharge Charge="" Amount="2.50"/>
          </Line>
        </Lines>
      </Ship>
      <Ship>
        <Lines>
          <Line ReferenceNumber="102">
            <LineCharge Charge="" Amount="5.62"/>
          </Line>
        </Lines>
      </Ship>
      <Ship>
        <Lines>
          <Line ReferenceNumber="103">
            <LineCharge Charge="" Amount="4.59"/>
            <LineCharge Charge="" Amount="9.97"/>
          </Line>
        </Lines>
      </Ship>
    </Ships>
  </Invoice>
</DocumentElement>
```